# How to color space between two lines with a colour transition?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, fill

How to colour space between two lines with a colour transition? For instance, with grey colour - the dark grey from the upper line should become lighter as proceeding to the lower line. Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = 0.3*x
ax.set_ylim(-0.2, 0.6)
ax.plot(x, y)
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
ax.plot(x, y - 0.1*width_l)

plt.show()
```

**Edit**

And this, please? How to make the width of the coloured part the same?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pywt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

wavelet = pywt.ContinuousWavelet('morl')
psi, x = wavelet.wavefun(level=2)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys_r')

ax.plot(x, psi)
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_xlim()[1])
y_a = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim(y_a[0],y_a[1]*1.3)
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
x_range = ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0]
x_shift = x_range * 0.1
ax.plot([x[0]+x_shift, x[1]+x_shift], [psi[0], psi[1]])
ax.plot([x[2]-x_shift, x[3]-x_shift], [psi[2], psi[3]])
ax.plot([x[1], x[2]], [psi[1]-width_l*0.1, psi[2]-width_l*0.1])

for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40):
    ax.plot(x, psi - t * 0.1 * width_l, color=cmap(t/2 + 0.25))

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw a lot of parallel lines (or curves) using a color from a gray-scale colormap. The example code below uses a transformation `u = t/2 + 0.25`, so when `t` goes from `0` to `1`, `u` would just go between `0.25` and `0.75` to select of specific range from the colormap, avoiding the very dark and very light parts.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = 0.3 * x
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
ax.set_ylim(-0.2, 0.6)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys_r')
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40):
    u = t/2 + 0.25
    ax.plot(x, y - t * 0.1 * width_l, color=cmap(u))
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x, y - 0.1 * width_l)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Could you help me also with the edit of the question, please?